# Find $\int_0^2 x^2f''(2x)dx $ given $f(2)$, $f'(2)$, and $\int_0^2 f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $$\int_0^2 x^2f''(2x)dx=$$
>   given $f(2)=\frac{1}{2}$, $f'(2)=0$, $\int_0^2 f(x)dx=1$.

Can anybody give me some hints？

Comment: Is $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$ valid?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean $\int_0^1 x^2 f''(2x)\, dx$. If not, it's a typo in your text.

Then, applying IBP twice and $u$-sub once:

$$\int_0^1 x^2 f''(2x)\, dx = \frac{x^2 f'(2x)}{2}\bigg{|}_0^1 - \int_0^1 \frac{f'(2x)}{2}2x \, dx$$
$$=\frac{x^2 f'(2x)}{2}\bigg{|}_0^1 -\left( \frac{x f(2x)}{2}\bigg{|}_0^1 - \int_0^1 \frac{f(2x)}{2}\, dx \right)$$
$$=0- \left(\frac{1}{4}-\int_0^2 \frac{f(x)}{4}\, dx\right)$$
$$=-\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\right)=0$$

Comment: yes,you're right.maybe it's a typo in the text.

Answer (score 1):

This problem just screams for tabular integration. $$\int_0^2 x^2f''(2x)dx = \left[\frac{x^2}{2}f'(2x)-\frac{x}{2}f(2x)\right]_0^2+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^2f(2x)dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use integration by parts, two times:
$$u=x^2\quad \text{and}\quad dv= f''(2x)dx$$

Comment: how to find $f(4)$ and $f'(4)$?

Comment: Okay, I think don't see how... wait one moment